# Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar

Tags: php, ios, laravel, composer-php

Having trouble installing composer if you can believe that.

ios sierra (10.12.6)

This is my code

```
Samers-MBP:~ samer$ php composer-setup.php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"

Composer (version 1.5.2) successfully installed to: 
/Users/samer/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar

Samers-MBP:~ samer$ php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
Samers-MBP:~ samer$ sudo mv /Users/samer/composer.phar 
/usr/local/bin/composer
Password:
Samers-MBP:~ samer$ composer
Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
Samers-MBP:~ samer$ cd /usr/local/bin
Samers-MBP:bin samer$ composer
Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
Samers-MBP:bin samer$
```

i can only run composer using SUDO

```
Samers-MBP:~ samer$ sudo composer info
Password:
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See 
https://getcomposer.org/root for details
nesbot/carbon             1.22.1  A simple API extension for DateTime.
symfony/polyfill-mbstring v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring 
extension
symfony/translation       v3.3.10 Symfony Translation Component
Samers-MBP:~ samer$
```

installed Laravel, but i cant access the `$HOME/.bashrc` ( Access Denied ) or `~/.bash_profile` to place composer's system-wide vendor bin directory in my $PATH...

i dunno what i did wrong or why its not working.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/composer*`?

Comment: `-rwxr-xr-x  1 samer  staff  1852323 Nov  8 16:44 /usr/local/bin/composer`

i can only run `composer` it using SUDO

Comment: and the output of `which composer`?

Comment: `Samers-MBP:~ samer$ sudo composer info  
Password:  
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details  
nesbot/carbon             1.22.1  A simple API extension for DateTime.  
symfony/polyfill-mbstring v1.6.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension  
symfony/translation       v3.3.10 Symfony Translation Component  
Samers-MBP:~ samer$ `

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem on MacOS Catalina after running the typical installation instructions:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '795f976fe0ebd8b75f26a6dd68f78fd3453ce79f32ecb33e7fd087d39bfeb978342fb73ac986cd4f54edd0dc902601dc') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt';         
unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

I suspected that it needed execute permissions. The initial permissions were:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 username  staff   1994202 Sep 25 08:39 composer
```

Though it had execute permissions for me, I changed it to make everything else in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   1994202 Sep 25 08:39 composer
```

I still had this error:

```
Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

I double checked my PATH variable:

```
% echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/php5/bin:...
```

I sourced my `bash_profile` file forgetting that I was on zsh, so I resourced my `zshrc` file.

```
% source ~/.bash_profile
% source ~/.zshrc
```

Still no dice. Eventually I changed the filename to composer.phar

```
% sudo mv /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
```

Then it worked

```
% composer
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                /_/
Composer version 1.10.13 2020-09-09 11:46:34
...
```

That's never been necessary in the past for me but for the moment it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Change the filename with below command on terminal

`sudo mv /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer.phar`

then type 'composer'

```
   ______
  / ____/___  ____ ___  ____  ____  ________  _____
 / /   / __ \/ __ `__ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ _ \/ ___/
/ /___/ /_/ / / / / / / /_/ / /_/ (__  )  __/ /
\____/\____/_/ /_/ /_/ .___/\____/____/\___/_/
                    /_/
Composer version 2.3.10 2022-07-13 15:48:23

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help                     Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet                    Do not output any message
  -V, --version                  Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi           Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction           Do not ask any interactive question
      --profile                  Display timing and memory usage information
      --no-plugins               Whether to disable plugins.
      --no-scripts               Skips the execution of all scripts defined in composer.json file.
  -d, --working-dir=WORKING-DIR  If specified, use the given directory as working directory.
      --no-cache                 Prevent use of the cache
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose           Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  about                Shows a short information about Composer.
  archive              Creates an archive of this composer package.
  browse               [home] Opens the package's repository URL or homepage in your browser.
  check-platform-reqs  Check that platform requirements are satisfied.
  clear-cache          [clearcache|cc] Clears composer's internal package cache.
  completion           Dump the shell completion script
  config               Sets config options.
  create-project       Creates new project from a package into given directory.
  depends              [why] Shows which packages cause the given package to be installed.
  diagnose             Diagnoses the system to identify common errors.
  dump-autoload        [dumpautoload] Dumps the autoloader.
  exec                 Executes a vendored binary/script.
  fund                 Discover how to help fund the maintenance of your dependencies.
  global               Allows running commands in the global composer dir ($COMPOSER_HOME).
  help                 Display help for a command
  init                 Creates a basic composer.json file in current directory.
  install              [i] Installs the project dependencies from the composer.lock file if present, or falls back on the composer.json.
  licenses             Shows information about licenses of dependencies.
  list                 List commands
  outdated             Shows a list of installed packages that have updates available, including their latest version.
  prohibits            [why-not] Shows which packages prevent the given package from being installed.
  reinstall            Uninstalls and reinstalls the given package names
  remove               Removes a package from the require or require-dev.
  require              Adds required packages to your composer.json and installs them.
  run-script           [run] Runs the scripts defined in composer.json.
  search               Searches for packages.
  self-update          [selfupdate] Updates composer.phar to the latest version.
  show                 [info] Shows information about packages.
  status               Shows a list of locally modified packages.
  suggests             Shows package suggestions.
  update               [u|upgrade] Updates your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file.
  validate             Validates a composer.json and composer.lock.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You must give it execute permissions:

Try this:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

And then

```
composer -v
```

Comment: `Samers-MBP:~ samer$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
    Password:
    Samers-MBP:~ samer$ composer -v
    Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
    Samers-MBP:~ samer$`

Answer (score 0):

Just perform the following steps for installing composer. You won't have any issues using composer on Mac:

```
sudo php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
sudo php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
sudo php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: `Samers-MBP:~ samer$ sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
Password:
Samers-MBP:~ samer$ composer -v Could not open input file: /usr/local/bin/composer.phar
Samers-MBP:~ samer$`

Comment: I've followed the steps and got a similar error. It seems with Catalina and maybe other versions the shell doesn't update fast enough (or something similar) and continues to reference composer.phar instead of composer.